# So you found $3000 under your couch. What do you buy?

Tags: fantasy, buy, gear, money

And you have to spend it. Because the couch-demons will come after it if you don't. And you have to spend it on audio stuff.

If it were me, I'd get either get a decent stereo shotgun (am undecided on what model... haven't tested yet) or a Paca (Kyma)

Comment: Don't forget to buy Angry Birds Super-Deluxe-Mega-Jumbo-Best Edition.

Comment: That would be badass…angry birds? come one, you've GOT to get no LESS than the super deluxe mega jumbo best edition…unless theres a sequel...

Comment: PACA! No other suggestions.

Answer (score 10):

I'd spend it on (field recording) travel - Indonesia, Japan, South Korea, VietNam, Cambodia....

Comment: travel indeed, southeast asia also sounds good, Bali, Java...

Comment: Plus one on the travel. I just did a trip to Vietnam and field recorded like mad. That country sounds like no other. I even recorded several hotel fans in a homage to Apocalypse....

Answer (score 9):

A sounddevices 702T and some of the independent sound libraries

Comment: Get me one while you are at it :-)

Comment: Ok, where is my couch :], my dream too.

Answer (score 5):

I'd buy a new couch.  Seriously, I hate mine.

Comment: @Chuck I can't tell you just how key a good couch is to getting audio work done.  Clients have nicknamed my couch "The Narcoleptic Throne." I wouldn't have it any other way. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd buy another couch in hopes of funding another $3000 underneath!

Barring that, I'd pickup Nuendo and an Apogee interface. It looks to be a serious challenger to PT9, would love to explore it in a professional film environment and see how they really stack up.

Comment: I just finished mixing a movie in Nuendo today, and although i'm a lot more clumsy with it than with pro tools i loved it. The stock plug ins sound great, and it has a loooot of really nice little functions!

By the way finished mixing at 2PM and the movie was screened at 8PM... phewww


Answer (score 3):

Reason, a KMR81, a convolution reverb (undecided), a service on the JBLs in my studio and indie FX libraries.

Or maybe i could use it to convince my boss to crossgrade from Euphonix MC Pro control module to a D Command.

Answer (score 3):

field recording mics (Sennheiser shotguns), and wind jammers

Answer (score 3):

@Chuck @Shaun - 
[The ultimate $3000 couch!](https://web.archive.org/web/20130623023751/http://www.asylum.com:80/2008/09/22/if-you-want-blue-balls-buy-this-3-000-couch)

[image]
<sub>(source: [freshome.com](http://freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/feel-sofa2.jpg))</sub>

Now that's what I call comfortable!

Comment: It's like sleeping on a bunch of grapes or blueberries.

Comment: Funny, I see a woman being eaten by a millipede.

Comment: Still cool though....

Answer (score 3):

A used muscle car, a Remington M580 shotgun, a box of shells, a potato sack, and a Ronald Reagan or clown mask. Then I'd rob a bank for the all-Schoeps collection that I'd really want.

I'd kick down some of the three gees for Bear McCreary to score the heist. ;-)

Comment: I wish i could up-vote this more times.

Comment: Totally.... for halveses on the mics I wear the Nixon mask.

Answer (score 2):

Schoeps CMIT5U and a decent recorder.

Or, if I have mics already, some good plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

A sound devices recorder, any model will do.

Comment: Same decision here... 

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem with purchase priorities all the time. I always try go for the option that will make me more money so I can afford to keep going down the list of potential gear purchases. Right now I'm torn between a laptop & PT9 or learning new software.  There's an audio implementation course I've been eyeing...

Comment: @Steve Can i ask where is that course?

Comment: @Filipe it's here http://www.berkleemusic.com/school/course?course_item_id=8688817&usca_p=t&offer_code=2285

Comment: Save your $.  You sound like you have some general audio post chops.  You can learn more by downloading FMOD or better yet Wwise (pc only i think) for free and fooling around (and maybe buying a book) than from a course.  It might be a bit frustrating at first, but you will learn it better.  And if you get stuck there's always SSD to the rescue.

Comment: @David I keep hearing this chorus and I'm starting to believe it. The laptop was within my grasp and then the funds ran away. But I'll have to add a copy of Windows7 to the list. As I'm a Mac guy it's the only thing keeping me from attempting this month's SD Challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Or 3000$ worth of scratch n' sniff cards

Answer (score 1):

need more than 3000$... :p

Comment: The couch apologizes - there's only $3000 in this couch. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I'd get my 'Opcode Rules' tattoo removed

Comment: no no, you're missing the point. You're not allowed to do something sensible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A computer and new DAW software.  It serves so many fuctions!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I suppose something shiny with the words "Sound Devices" on it would do. Any leftover change would go to the wife in an attempt to ease her anger. :P

Answer (score 0):

3000 scratch cards :)

Answer (score 0):

A DSI synth and some eurorack modules

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Sound Devices 702, a small petrol bag to go with it and then a fast CF card with ginormous capacity. I better go look under my couch again...

Answer (score 0):

I'd make me some headphones based on my custom HTRF that could emmulate playback in a dolby certified theatrical stage. That way I could really prep work at home in my project studio.

The Realiser A8. Price US$3000 ex shipping, complete with measurement microphones, head-tracker and Stax headphones+amp (Basic Stax set). .....http://smyth-research.com/products.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd get both a Schoeps and a Sennheiser hyper so I could stop agonizing over this decision!!!

Answer (score 0):

PSI reference speakers

Answer (score 0):

Buy a ticket to attend the royal wedding.

and record it lol

maybe not the wedding itself but the deserted streets of london - I could get a pure Big Ben ring with no traffic!

Answer (score 0):

Buy a few hours of Ben Burtt's time :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go Johnny Mnemonic and take out a piece of my brain and replace it with a couple hundred gigs of solid state memory.  Then I'd have three XLR plugs, and three Sound Devices pres jacked into the base of my spine and routed up my spinal column to the memory cards.  Then I'd have Apogee design me some micro A/D converters.

*Then* I'd put on my tri-aural sono-glasses and go walkabout.

Answer (score 0):

[Black Lion Audio Signature modded Digi 003r](http://blacklionaudio.com/content.php?p=8), and a [Rode NGT-3 Ultimate Bundle from Performance Audio](http://www.performanceaudio.com/cgi/product_view.cgi?products_id=21499).

Answer (score 0):

A ticket to the Seychelles - for field recording purpose of course.. ambiences in cocktail bars, sand moving slowly on the beach, waves clapping lazily against my boat... don't expect me to be back any time soon.